# Drawable vector resized incorrectly

Tags: android, svg, vector, adobe-illustrator, android-vectordrawable

I created a logo in `Adobe Illustrator`, exported it as `SVG` and imported it to Android Studio through `Asset Studio`.

When the vector is painted big, it is resized correctly (image 1), but when it's small (image 2), something goes wrong.

[image: Big vector] 
[image: Little vector]

Both are `ImageView`, the second one is inside the `Toolbar`.

Here is the vector:

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="128.0"
    android:viewportWidth="128.0"
    android:width="24dp" >
    <path android:fillColor="#7c7c7c" android:pathData="M64,64m-64,0a64,64 0,1 1,128 0a64,64 0,1 1,-128 0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#0b5c5d" android:pathData="M63.91,63.91m-57.6,0a57.6,57.6 0,1 1,115.2 0a57.6,57.6 0,1 1,-115.2 0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M77.31,16.23s-25.13,0.69 -40.7,5.59c-24.64,8.76 -23.73,45.63 -6.94,56C35.88,82.05 61.59,80 61.59,80l5.32,-15.27s-17.23,5.49 -28.67,-1.47C34.3,61.12 31.87,44 40,36.94S75.16,33.3 75.16,33.3Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M51.87,43c15.77,2.66 54.59,-3.2 55.95,-3.53 1.56,-0.39 -23.14,37.71 -29,51.92A73.06,73.06 0,0 0,105.28 90s-4.91,12.15 -4.88,16.64c-7.3,-1.58 -41.33,-4.25 -50.87,-3 4.3,-4.55 27.39,-38.13 31.4,-47 -12.16,0.39 -17.8,-0.47 -33.51,0.06C49.18,53.29 51.6,49.79 51.87,43Z"/>
</vector>
```

I have no idea what is happening.

When exporting the `SVG` from `Adobe Illustrator` I tried changing the decimal count, resizing the document to be bigger and smaller and other settings in the dialog.

Comment: post your toolbar tag code from layout file

Comment: The vector looks good, post the code of your toolbar.

Comment: Make sure you use the latest support library and `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src` (if you use AppCompat) or `VectorDrawableCompat`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello please check my below code i already check this with pragmatically and i got correct output.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_drawable" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

If you are using other layout for toolbar then include those toolbar into those between then it's fine.

If you have still problem after this try then please put your xml code so i can check and solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to your `drawable xml`:

You have to create copy of this drawable to use in toolbar, for this toolbar you have to reduce the view port size here with toolbar height and weidth.

```
android:viewportHeight="YOUR TOOLBAR HEIGHT"
android:viewportWidth="YOUR TOOLBAR HEIGHT (to make it square)"
```